# How to create parquet partitioned table

Tags: amazon-athena

Here is a sample create table statement that works as expected.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.reviews(
  marketplace varchar(10), 
  customer_id varchar(15), 
  review_id varchar(15), 
  product_id varchar(25), 
  product_parent varchar(15), 
  product_title varchar(50), 
  star_rating int, 
  helpful_votes int, 
  total_votes int, 
  vine varchar(5), 
  verified_purchase varchar(5), 
  review_headline varchar(25), 
  review_body varchar(1024), 
  review_date date, 
  year int)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  product_category varchar(25))
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/';
```

When I repair the table, I get an error:

> MSCK REPAIR TABLE  default.reviews
>
> Partitions not in metastore:  reviews:product_category=Apparel    reviews:product_category=Automotive

1. If the Partition is not in metastore, how do I get a count of 3.5 million?

   ```sql
   SELECT 
       COUNT(*) 
   FROM 
       "default"."reviews" 
   WHERE 
       product_category='Automotive'

   -- OUTPUT
   3516476
   ```
2. How do I make sure that all the records are correctly read and available?
3. How was this parquet partitioned table was created? I am asking because I have a csv table that I will like to partition exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Concept of partitioning is used in Athena only to restrict which "directories" should be scanned for data.
   Since `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` command failed, no partitions were created. Therefore, `WHERE product_category='Automotive'`
   doesn't have any affect and I'd say that **3516476** is the total number of rows in all csv files under `s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/`.

   Note, `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` would only work if "folder" structure on AWS S3 adheres HIVE convention:

   ```
   s3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/
   |
   ├── product_category=Apparel
   │   ├── file_1.csv
   │   | ...
   │   └── file_N.csv
   |                                 
   ├── product_category=Automotive
   │   ├── file_1.csv
   │   | ...
   │   └── file_M.csv
   ```
2. In order to ensure that all records are **correctly read** you have to make sure that table definition is correct.
   In order to ensure that all records are **available** you have to make sure that `LOCATION` points to the root
   "directory" of where all files are located on S3.
3. If you have a huge csv file with columns `col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4` and you want to partition it by `col_4` you would
   need to use [`CTAS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) query statements, however, keep in mind 
   [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/considerations-ctas.html) of such statements.

   Alternatively, if you already have multiple csv files each of which corresponds to a single value from `col_4`, then 
   simply upload them onto S3 in a way mentioned above. Then you should use combination of the following DDL statements:

   ```sql
   -- FIRST STATMENT
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_database`.`my_table`(
     `col_1` string, 
     `col_2` string, 
     `col_3` string,
     )
   PARTITIONED BY ( 
     `col_4` string)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 
     -- CHANGE AS APPROPRIATE
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
   STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
     -- CHANGE AS APPROPRIATE 
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
   OUTPUTFORMAT
     -- CHANGE AS APPROPRIATE 
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
   LOCATION
     's3://amazon-reviews-pds/parquet/';

   -- SECOND STATEMENT
   MSCK REPAIR TABLE `my_database`.`my_table`
   ```